# which part is the fingerprint in gpg public key

Tags: debian, gpg, fingerprint

I am using gpg -

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12
libgcrypt 1.8.4
```

I am trying to understand the difference between the two commands :

```
$ gpg --list-key
```

and:

```
$ gpg --fingerprint
```

from whatever little I see, I don't see any difference between two outputs. Am I looking at something wrong ?

Comment: They both produce the same output, except `--fingerprint` outputs its hex code into 10 groups of 4 numbers, instead of bunching them as one string of 40 hex numbers as with `--list-key`.

Comment: It is my answer as a comment. :-)

Comment: make it as an answer that was what @GAD3R was saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `--fingerprint` option prints the fingerprint into 10 groups of 4 caracters to easily verify the gpg key.